# AWK: How to decrement values in a column by one

Tags: awk, increment

I have a set of values in a column that go

```
3  
4  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
...
```

I wish to decrement all these values by 1

Any ideas as to how to formulate this in an AWK script?

thanks

---

What if I wish to increment the entries instead of decrementing?

Would awk '{ $7--; print $1 }' work?

Answer (score 7):

If it's just a single column, this will do:

```
awk '{ $7--; print $0 }'
```

Instead of the '7' in '$7' you need to insert your column number; if this number is greater 10, write it as $(77), e.g.

If all columns of a row are affected, use this:

```
awk '{ for (f=1; f<=NF; f--) $f--
       print $0
      }'
```

Hope this helps,

Klaus

Comment: I am sorry, the document is rather large. I will try an explain again:  One of the columns has entries 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .... until 2012 I want to decrement these so the column says 2 3 4 5 .... until 2011 any help here?

Comment: @christian the proposed solution (the first grayed code in this answer) does exactly what you want. Just be sure to replace the $7 by your column number

Answer (score 0):

If they're in column 4, `$4--`, and then do whatever else you were going to do (e.g. print).

Comment: This is not a full script, but this is the part of script which would decrement the numbers in the fourth column by one, yes.